# List view item click color indication programatically

Tags: android, listview

I have a list view with items, colored white background, I'd like the user interaction to be more clear when user clicks on item, make the background color different than white.
How do I implement this with **code** (**no xml**)?

Comment: I tried to change selection mode, without success

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a selector xml file in your "drawable" folder and use it as the background of your items, for example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item 
    android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/itemPressedColor" />
<item 
    android:state_pressed="false"
    android:drawable="@drawable/itemNormalColor" />
</selector>
```

Where itemPressedColor and itemNormalColor would be drawables defined in the same folder

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `selector` drawable, something like this:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/red"
          android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/white" />
</selector>
```

And then set this drawable as the background of your list item.

To do the same in code, you need to implement a custom adapter and in its `getView()` method use code like this:

```
StateListDrawable selector = new StateListDrawable();
selector.addState(new int[] { android.R.attr.state_pressed }, getResources().getDrawable(R.color.red));
selector.addState(new int[] {}, getResources().getDrawable(R.color.white));
...
View item = ...
item.setBackgroundDrawable(selector);
```

Comment: @ChenKinnrot I updated my answer to explain how to do the same in code

Answer (score 0):

Use [State List](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList) for xml **or** [State list Drawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/StateListDrawable.html) in code